# Pareto chart showing 10 largest values

Tags: r, dplyr, qcc, r-table

I want to display a pareto chart that shows only the largest 10 values. With the code below I can get the Pareto chart but the dataset is too large so that there is too much noise and certain datapoints are not visible.

```
library(qcc)
df = TestData$Amount
names(df) = TestData$CarType
pareto.chart(df)
```

I already thought and tried adding an array from [1:10] to get the top ten but the dataset is then not ordered - he is picking the first ten values randomly.

| CarType | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Audi | 12.546 |
| Mercedes | 6.767 |
| VW | 3.556 |
| Skoda | 5.768 |
| Bentley | 1.657 |
| Ford | 2.934 |
| Lexus | 15.567 |
| Mitsubishi | 532 |
| Hyundai | 8.611 |
| BMW | 213 |
| Scania | 4.450 |
| Volvo | 10.123 |

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, could you add an example of your dataset ? `dput(TestData)` would be great

Comment: Yes, refresh the feed :)

Answer (score 0):

We can order the `Amount` column by decreasing value with the function `order` and select the 10 first lines as you mentioned in your post :

```
library(qcc)
df = TestData$Amount
names(df) = TestData$CarType
df=df[order(-df)][1:10]
pareto.chart(df)
```

Comment: Thank you or should I say merci! That’s workin fine :) I should be reading more documentations

Answer (score 0):

You can get top 10 values by -

```
library(dplyr)

df <- TestData %>% arrange(Amount) %>% slice(1:10)

#also
df <- TestData %>% slice_max(Amount, n = 10)
```

Or in base R -

```
df <- TestData[with(TestData, tail(order(Amount), 10)), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- head(setDT(TestData)[order(Amount)], 10)
```